# url encode a utf-8 string in c?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, urlencode

Should I write my own or is there a library function that already does that? I need this for a pidgin plugin, so if there is something in the pidgin/purple/gnome libraries, that would be ideal. But other sources are fine, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [apreq_encode()](http://httpd.apache.org/apreq/docs/libapreq2/apreq__util_8h.html#74bbf602809048452bbdbe886ceef023) from [libapreq2](http://httpd.apache.org/apreq/docs/libapreq2/).  Note that your write buffer needs to be `3 * src_length + 1` big, which isn't necessarily clear from the doc snippet.